# Trying to put a div next to a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been searching for a while for a responsive slider and I finally one.
 I changed the width so that it only takes up half the page because on the other half I would like to have an area of text.
However the text goes underneath the slider and to the right instead of just directly to the right.
 I'm hoping that a second pair of eyes can help me catch the mistake I'm making.

```css
.home-content {
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 90%;
 padding-top: 3em;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
}
#slides {
 float: left;
}
#latest-posts {
 float: right;
}
.rslides {
   position: relative;
   top: 1em;
   list-style: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 50%;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

.rslides li {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   display: none;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   float: left;
}

.rslides img {
   display: block;
   height: auto;
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-content">
  <div id="slides">
   <ul class="rslides">
      <li><img src="../images/slider/test-slide-1.svg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="../images/slider/test-slide-2.svg" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="latest-posts">
   <p>TEST TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` and `float: right` along with percentage widths for `#slides` and `#latest-posts`.

```css
.home-content {
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 90%;
 padding-top: 3em;
 margin-left: auto;
        text-align: center;
 margin-right: auto;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000;
}
#slides {
 display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 49%;
}
#latest-posts {
 display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 49%;
}
.rslides {
   position: relative;
   list-style: none;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

.rslides li {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   display: none;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
}

.rslides li:first-child {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   float: left;
}

.rslides img {
   display: block;
   height: auto;
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-content">
  <div id="slides">
   <ul class="rslides">
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x150" alt=""></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="latest-posts">
   <p>TEST TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to be a step in the right direction although now the text is directly underneath the slider and to the left. I can see the bottom of the text behind the slider.

Comment: It seems something in the slider is keeping the slider from being restricted to the div because if I set the slider width to 100% it takes up the entire page instead of being confined to the 49% div that it is in.

Comment: @Bob Are you previewing my snippet above? It's appearing perfectly inside that.

Comment: Hm interesting, let me try duplicating that better.

Comment: I must have missed something before, it works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @bob You're welcome, I am glad it works perfectly as per your needs.